# JavaScript element traversal returning more than expected

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a simple HTML setup as follows:

```
<div>
outer
    <div>Inner</div>
</div>
```

I am traversing it as follows:

```
"use strict";

var divs = document.getElementsByTagName( "div" );

for( var i = 0, div; div = divs[i]; i++ ) {
    console.log( div.innerText );
}
```

Output:

```
outer
Inner
Inner
```

Why is `Inner` output twice?

Comment: BTW, the W3C compliant [*textContent*](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#Node3-textContent) property is preferred over the MS proprietary [*innerText*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms533899(v=vs.85).aspx), which is not supported by all browsers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get it twice because the divs are nested. It reads all of the text of the element and its siblings.

- First one's text is `outer inner`
- Second one's text is just `innner`.

Comment: @samyismyhero: If you only want to get the text nodes that are children of the element node, iterate over the element's child nodes and filter out the text nodes.